# Ratio test for testing the convergence of infinite series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am wondering does it make a difference for the ratio test if $a_n$ is a series and we take $lim |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|$ will it be the same as taking the limit $lim |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = l \not=0$, then $\lim \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{l}$, so it doesn't really make a difference as long as you reverse the test's condition...
You can check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test